# Asynchronous operations from WCF service or ASP.NET

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, wcf-ria-services, invocation

I'm developing an application using WCF Ria services and Silverlight. Performance and scalability is a must in this project. The problem is that I have to invoke several WCF services from RIA Service, and service invocation takes time. Threads are limited resource on the webserver, so when I invoke a service, the executing thread just hangs and waits for the answer. This is not acceptable in my sitation. I remember there was a way to workaround this issue back in .NET 2 days, I guess there is still now, but don't remember anything. Any memory refreshment would be nice :)

Thanks

Comment: And what kind of workaround would that have been?  Time-travel?

Comment: Well, there is a possibility to execute the wcf service asyncrhonously, which will return executing thread to thred pool. Client will receive response from the server when the service invocation is finished. I mean, the thread is recovered from thread pool after service invocation finishes.

Comment: You probably mean asynchronous asp.net pages from ASP.NET 2.0 which returned thread to thread pool during external asynchronous processing. WCF also offers asynchronous operations but the question is how this works with RIA services (I have never even try them so I don't know): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177.aspx

Comment: @Ladislav yes, that's what I mean. Thanks :) I'll take a look to the url, maybe someone will post how it works with ria services.

Comment: One way I do multiple requests as a unit of work is to create a View Model which encapsulates multiple calls into a single call.  I find this reduces the workload on the client as well and allows the server to manage the whole process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like standard asynch pattern is the right way to go. Thanks to Ladislav Mrnka for pointing me to the right direction.